# atmega16 programmable flash memory (the meaning of Read-While-Write capabilities)

Tags: microcontroller

I'm new to MCUs, I am learning avr , in atmega16 data sheet i read that The ATmega16 provides the following features: 16K bytes of In-System Programmable Flash Program memory with Read-While-Write capabilities, what read-while-write means and How could it happen while there only one instruction bus , one instruction address bus.

Comment: It most likely means that simultaneous reading and writing are supported. However, it's possible that those must occur in distinct regions (e.g. while writing is happening at an address between 1KB and 2KB, reading isn't permitted in the same range, but is OK below 1KB and above 2KB). Please see the documentation for further details.

Comment: Thank you. @AlexeyFrunze